# android EditText内の初期設定されている文字を、クリック時にクリアする方法

Tags: java, android, xml

現在、発音チェックアプリを作っています。
以下の方法でチェックする仕様です。
１：EditTextに、チェックする単語または文章を入力する。
２：音声認識機能を呼び出し、TextViewに発音した音声をセットする。
３：EditText内の文字とTextView内の文字が同じかを判定する。

流れは以上の通りです。
現在、EditTextに初期設定として「文字を入力してください」という文章が設定されています。
EditText内に単語を入力する際、上記の初期設定している文章を消さなくてはいけません。
めんどくさいです。

EditText内の文字を、EditTextをクリックするだけ消えるようにするには、どうすればいいですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hintプロパティを追加すればできるかと思います．
HTMLでいうplaceholderみたいなやつです．

XMLに記述する場合は

```
android:hint="文字を入力してください"
```

kotlinとかjavaとかで記述する場合は

```
editText.setHint("文字を入力してください");  // java
editText.hint = "文字を入力してください"     // kotlin
```

です．
ここで，editTextはEditTextオブジェクトですので，XMLにあるやつをfindViewByIdで探してくるか，新しくインスタンス化したものを使えば大丈夫です．